# C++ builder package export link error

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder, bpl

I create a *.bpl project **BPL_A** which contain a TForm subclass, say **TForm_Sub**.

The header file **Form_Sub.h** is like following:

```
class PACKAGE TForm_Sub : public TForm
{
   ...
};

extern PACKAGE TForm_Sub* Form_Sub;
```

The source file **Form_Sub.cpp** is like following:

```
TForm_Sub* Form_Sub;

__fastcall TForm_Sub::TForm_Sub( TComponent* Owner )
{
   ...
}
```

And I create another *.bpl project **BPL_B** to dynamically create TForm_Sub instance.

```
class PACKAGE SomeClass
{
   public:
      TForm* CreateUI( const AnsiString& name );
};

#include "Form_Sub.h"

TForm* SomeClass::CreateUI( const AnsiString& name )
{
   if( name == xxx )
   {
      if( Form_Sub != NULL )
      {
         Form_Sub = new TForm_Sub( owner );
      }
      return Form_Sub;
   }
}
```

I add BPL_A.bpi to Requires section of BPL_B. However, I get following link error when building BPL_B.

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: Export SomeClass::CreateUI() in module xxx.OBJ references __fastcall TForm_Sub::TForm_Sub() in unit BPL_A]Form_Sub.

I can not figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `#pragma package(smart_init)` directive to the source (xxx.cpp) file.

According to the [C++builder help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Export_%27symbol%27_in_module_%27module%27_references_%27symbol%27_in_unit_%27unit%27):

> **Export 'symbol' in module 'module' references 'symbol' in unit 'unit'**
>
> You are attempting to export a symbol from a module that is not a unit (does not contain the `#pragma package(smart_init)` directive) and it references a symbol in a unit. This is not allowed because if you have such a symbol, then someone can link to its import; and when the import is called, it calls into the unit code. If the client of the exported non-unit function did not reference anything from the unit, it will never be initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @manlio. I add `#pragma package(smart_init) directive` in front of SomeClass .cpp file, and it works.